# Initialize nested struct using new

Tags: go, struct, new-operator

This is my Go code. Also available at [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/asCughOLQBj)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type App struct {
    OneHandler *OneHandler
    TwoHandler *TwoHandler
}
type OneHandler struct {
}
type TwoHandler struct {
    NestedTwoHandler *NestedTwoHandler
}
type NestedTwoHandler struct {
    NestedNestedTwoHandler *NestedNestedTwoHandler
}
type NestedNestedTwoHandler struct {
}

func main() {
    app := &App{
        OneHandler: new(OneHandler),
        TwoHandler: new(TwoHandler),
    }

    fmt.Println(*app)
    fmt.Println(*app.OneHandler)
    fmt.Println(*app.TwoHandler)
}
```

Its output is

```
{0x19583c 0x1040c128}
{}
{<nil>}
```

Why is `NestedTwoHandler` `nil`? I was expecting it to be `{some_pointer_location}` with `NestedNestedTwoHandler` being `{}`. How can I create an empty deep nested struct using `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new(TwoHandler)` is creating a new instance of struct `TwoHandler`. All its fields will have zero values. For a pointer type, this is `nil`, so that is what `NestedTwoHandler` will be unless you specify it.

`new` only zeroes memory, so if you want to initialize anything, you need to use something else such as a [composite literal](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals):

```
    TwoHandler: &TwoHandler{new(NestedTwoHandler)},
```

This creates a pointer to a `TwoHandler` struct with the only field set to a new `NestedTwoHandler`. Note that `TwoHandler.NesterTwoHandler.NestedNestedTwoHandler` will be `nil` as we're using `new` again, so it remains the zero value.

You can keep initializing fields using literals:

```
    TwoHandler: &TwoHandler{&NestedTwoHandler{new(NestedNestedTwoHandler)}}
```

You can read more details about [allocating with new](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new).